# Xamarin Forms - shadow for Master Detail Page action bar on Android

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I have Xamarin Forms Master Detail page (Android) and need to add shadow for top navigation bar. I tried it this way: https://xamgirl.com/navigation-bar-with-shadow-in-xamarin-forms/ but shadow is shown above navigation button, i need it below.

I guess i need to create custom renderer for master detail page but that seems like a lot of work.

[image: what i have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use frame on top of each content page:

```
<Frame HeightRequest="2" 
  HasShadow="True"  
  Padding="0" 
  CornerRadius="0"
  MinimumHeightRequest="1" 
  VerticalOptions="Start" 
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```